# Version 4.6.4 no longer available?

Tags: version, openlayers, missing-data

We use version 4.6.4 of openlayers but this version suddenly disappeared. Now we receive the following error:

```
GET https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Version 4.6.5 is still available though but we still need 4.6.4

Is this an error or are we forced to upgrade?

Comment: I think you should ask this in [openlayers issues section on github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues) instead?

Comment: It's still available on other cdn services along with all other versions since 2.11 https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openlayers/4.6.4